# How to use a Spilhaus/ESRI:54099 projection in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, proj

I am trying to make a map using a Spilhaus projection, similar to the one implemented by Esri [here](https://storymaps.arcgis.com/stories/756bcae18d304a1eac140f19f4d5cb3d). QGIS has ESRI:54099 WGS_1984_Spilhaus_Ocean_Map_in_Square in its list of available projections, however when I select it the window goes blank and my data is not visible. When I change the projection to something else the data becomes visible again. I've tried clicking zoom to layer, but to no avail.

[This forum post](https://georezo.net/forum/viewtopic.php?id=122035)(French) says that because this Spilhaus is not supported by Proj, it is not supported by QGIS. [This page](https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/issues/1851) seems to confirm that Spilhaus-implementation in proj is still ongoing/has not been accomplished. Is this the root-cause of my problem, and therefor I am out of luck? Or is there some other problem, since ESRI:54099 is in the list of projections available in QGIS I'd hoped it would work.

When I try reprojecting my data (downloaded from Natural Earth) into ESRI:54099 I get an error: `Feature creation error (OGR error: Coordinates with non-finite values are not allowed)`.

Does anyone know how to implement a Spilhaus projection in QGIS?

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: Unfortunately not, didn't work further on this.

Comment: What steps would need to be taken to make it possible?

Comment: I do not think there is a plan for the immediate.